# How do I pass ">>" or "<<" to my script without the terminal trying to interpret it as me either appending to something or getting stdin?

Tags: linux, bash

My python script can take a series of bitwise operators as one of its arguments. They all work fine except for "=<<" which is roll left, and "=>>" which is roll right. I run my script like `./script.py -b +4,-4,=>>10,=<<1`, where anything after -b can be any combination of similar operations. As soon as the terminal sees "<<" though, it just drops the cursor to a new line after the command and asks for more input instead of running the script. When it sees ">>", my script doesn't process the arguments correctly. I know it's because bash uses these characters for a specific purpose, but I'd like to get around it while still using "=>>" and "=<<" in my arguments for my script. Is there any way to do it without enclosing the argument in quotation marks?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: `cat | ./script.py -b` ?

Comment: A shell command is necessarily written in the shell language, and in the shell language an unquoted `>>` *means* append output to a file, and `<<` means read input from a here-document. You cannot make your command have its own custom syntax; it's a shell command, and therefore subject to shell syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should enclose the parameters that contain special symbols into single quotation marks (here, `echo` represents your script):

```
> echo '+4,-4,=>>10,=<<1'
+4,-4,=>>10,=<<1
```

Alternatively, save the parameters to a file (say, `params.txt`) and read them from the file onto the command line using the backticks:

```
> echo `cat params.txt`
+4,-4,=>>10,=<<1
```

Lastly, you can escape some offending symbols:

```
> echo +4,-4,=\>\>10,=\<\<1
+4,-4,=>>10,=<<1
```

Comment: And also maybe remove the single quotation marks when reading the parameter from the script. Or maybe `echo '+4,-4,=>>10,=<<1' |./script.py -b`

Comment: @ChatterOne I am not sure what you mean. Nothing is read from a script.

Comment: I mean that the python script (the `./script.py` ) will read the parameter as literally `'+4,-4,=>>10,=<<1'`, so when using that value, the quotation marks will need to be removed first

Comment: @ChatterOne That would be an answer to a different question, and surely not related to my answer.

Comment: I'm not trying to be smart or anything, but yes, it is related to your answer because if you use quotation marks you're passing a different parameter, so the python script needs to be slightly adjusted. It's not a big deal, just something to say because `./script.py -b '+4,-4,=>>10,=<<1'` will not work without changing the python script

Comment: @ChatterOne This is not true. The quotes will not be seen by the script. Have you tried?